# Apex Upgrade 5.1 - 19.1, what is likely to break?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Hi there I'm creating a inventory database system using oracle apex currently my place of employment is using apex 5.1 but are looking to upgrade to the new version (19.1) shortly after my contract ends I'm curious if anyone is aware of anything, in particular, that is going to break or is more likely to break, (ie master detail) so that it can be avoided or documented

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, nothing will "break" (meaning: you won't get any ORA-xxxxx errors), but some things won't work any more (which is maybe even worse; if there was an error, you'd look at it and, possibly, fix it).

The old tabular forms were ugly and kind of difficult to work with. Interactive grid is prettier, but I hate it & try not to use it whenever possible (what do I do, then? Use Interactive report + form). If you decide to upgrade tabular forms into interactive grids, note that code you might have written probably won't work.

Yet another thing: charts. The ones I had in 5.1 simply disappeared in 18.2 (OK, you'll upgrade to 19.1, but nonetheless ...). New charts are beautiful, but it'll take some time to fix them.

Finally, trees. I've used icons which helped users to easily distinguish values that are ON (green icons) from those that are OFF (red icons). In a new version, icons aren't visible any more and everything looks just the same; I have no idea what's ON and what's OFF.

Now, a question for you: why don't you upgrade *now*, before you create that application? If that isn't possible, consider installing XE database, put Apex 19.1 onto it and develop the application there. When the company you work with does the upgrade, the application should be OK.